# How I can Copy file by command line in android?

Tags: android, shell

I want to copy file from `data/data/mypackage` to `/mnt/sdcard` but when i apply the command line nothing happened. My mobile is rooted and I have permeation to make this command.I have array list and put all  my command inside this array after  get all command "`getCommandsToExecute()`" method and apply all my command:

```
public final boolean execute() {
        boolean retval = false;

        try {
            ArrayList<String> commands = getCommandsToExecute();
            if (null != commands && commands.size() > 0) {
                Process suProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");

                DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(
                        suProcess.getOutputStream());

                // Execute commands that require root access
                for (String currCommand : commands) {
                    os.writeBytes(currCommand + "\n");
                    os.flush();
                }

                os.writeBytes("exit\n");
                os.flush();

                try {
                    int suProcessRetval = suProcess.waitFor();
                    if (255 != suProcessRetval) {
                        // Root access granted
                        retval = true;
                    } else {
                        // Root access denied
                        retval = false;
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Log.e("ROOT", "Error executing root action", ex);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.w("ROOT", "Can't get root access", ex);
        } catch (SecurityException ex) {
            Log.w("ROOT", "Can't get root access", ex);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.w("ROOT", "Error executing internal operation", ex);
        }

        return retval;
    }
```

My array list have this command:

```
ArrayList<String> hi= new ArrayList<String>();
hi.add("shell cp /data/data/com.askfm/databases /mnt/sdcard");
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `cat src >dest`

There's no `cp` command in an out-of-box Android. There are tools like BusyBox ([here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=stericson.busybox&hl=en), [there](http://www.busybox.net/)), but they must be installed separately.